# Nuxt _vm._ssrNode is not a function when running yarn dev

Tags: nuxt.js, node-modules, package.json

I'm getting `_vm._ssrNode is not a function` when trying to run my project.

Yarn dev just runs nuxt, which presumably runs `node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js` which, when I run it myself `./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js` results in the same error.

When I run Nuxt from the CLI e.g. `nuxt` which is  located at `/home/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/bin/nuxt`, the app runs perfectly.

More information:

```
./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js --version
@nuxt/cli v2.15.2

nuxt --version
@nuxt/cli v2.14.12
```

But in package.json:

```
"nuxt": "^2.15.2",
```

I will be trying to forcibly update, and I have tried deleting my yarn.lock and node_modules but it didn't seem to work. My colleague also had the same issue.

I will also try downgrading.
Edit:

Specifying the Nuxt version as `"nuxt": "~2.14.12"` did set the same version of Nuxt in node_modules, but I'm now getting an error:

```
ERROR in ./.nuxt/client.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: /<user>/nuxtapp/.nuxt/client.js: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/lib/utils'
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I've resolved this with 

`  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.17"
  }` specified in the package.json with nuxt downgraded 2.14.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to downgrade in order to resolve this issue.

I updated `nuxt` in my package.json to version `"~2.14.12"`, and hit [an issue raised on Github](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8882).

Setting some [resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

```
 "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.17"
  }
```

Resolved this, and allowed me to build.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out to be any functional components. When those were turned back to regular components OR were wrapped in `<client-only>` all was fine.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of SSR but yes, there was also a problem with functional components in my project. To me, this is more of a self-inflicted regression than simply downgrading the Nuxt version  and waiting to see if they resolve this in the future

Comment: Yeah good point @Jonathan. Same here. I didn't use too many functional components where regular components were suitable. I kept with the latest deps so that I could keep moving forward with other bug fixes but just noted to check back in when it eventually is resolved.